# Are there some commutative function to produce (pseudo) random numbers?

Tags: computer-science, cyclic-groups, cryptography, random

I'm looking for functions $f_1, f_2$ which are commutative to each other.

$$f_1(f_2(x)) = f_2(f_1(x))$$

Random numbers $r_{i,j}$ should be computed in a chain/sequence:
$$r_{i+1,j} = f_1(r(i,j)) $$
$$r_{i,j+1} = f_2(r(i,j)) $$
$$r_{i+1,j+1} = f_1(f_2(r(i,j))) = f_2(f_1(r(i,j)))$$

They need to produce many but finite amount of numbers. If with given $r_{0,0}$ the funtion $f_1(x)$ can produce $s_1$ unique numbers and $f_2(x)$ can produce $s_2$ unique numbers than $f_1(f_2(x))$ should be able to produce $N$ numbers with $N>s_1,s_2, s_1+s_2$. It should be  at least $\mathcal{O}(s_1\cdot s_2)$

There should be no close form for $r_{i,j}$ with given $r_{0,0}$. Or as alternative the computation as least as hard as generating all variables in between.

If a random variable $v$ is known to be part of the sequence starting at $r_{0,0}$ with $v = r_{a,b}$ for unknown $a,b$ it should take in mean $\mathcal{O}(a\cdot b \cdot \mathcal{O}(f) )$ operations to find $a,b$. That also means if $a,b$ is known it does not help for finding another sequence element $r_{c,d}$ for the case $c=a$ or $d=b$.
EDIT: As  Misha Lavrov wrote in comments $\mathcal{O}(a\cdot b \cdot\mathcal {O}(f) )$ is not possible if there is also a inverse function with same computation time. Only $\mathcal{O}(a + b)\mathcal{O}(f)$ steps are needed. For simplicity I only wrote about two functions $f_1,f_2$. In target usage I have 3 of them so it would be $r_{a,b,c}$. For this the product should work again at least with two factors. With 3 functions $\mathcal{O}( (a + b)\cdot c)\mathcal{O}(f)$ steps are needed ($a,b,c$ can be permuted to get lowest value).
(end of EDIT)

If $f_1,f_2$ is not valid for all $r_{0,0}$ there should be a way to validate if a random value $r_{0,0}$ is suitable or not.

Furthermore there need to exists a inverse function of $f_1, f_2$ which has about the same computation time.

---

Solution can include some special kind of groups, rings, hypercomplex numbers or anything else. Only condition $r_{i+1,j}, r_{i,j+1}$ need to be computable at a PC with storage less than the total number of unique numbers $N$.

### Target application

Needed for an arrangement of unique values with certain size. Too many to store them all, too less to use common cryptography methods like elliptic curves in each dimension. Only the product of the size in each dimension is big enough to have some long enough computation time. Use case need 3 functions $f_1,f_2,f_3$ which are commutative. The randomness of those values don't need to pass any tests for randomization. The only requirement is they give no clue about the index related to $r_{0,0}$.
The $r_{0,0}$ is random. Same $r_{0,0}$ should give same set $R=\{r_{i,j} \forall i,j\}$. A different $r_{0,0}'$ can produce a different set $R'=\{r_{i,j}' \forall i,j\}\neq R$. The amount of different sets is limited. It should be much smaller than the amount of different $r_{0,0}$

### Functions which don't work

-Binary XOR functions are commutative but they can only produce a very small amount of unique numbers.

-Cyclic group with generators $g,h$ and suitable prime $P$ which has the form:
$$g^i h^j \mod P$$
$$f_1(x) = x\cdot g \mod P$$
$$f_2(x) = x\cdot h \mod P$$
This can be reduced to a problem of just finding $i$ or $j$. So the problem scales with the max cycle size and not with their product.

-Chebyshev polynomials are commutative functions. Did some tests with 
$$f_1(x) = T_n(x) \mod P$$
$$f_2(x) = T_{n+1}(x) \mod P$$
with suitable $P$ and $r_{0,0}$ they can produce up to a $P/4$ different numbers. But if $f_1,f_2$ used together the total amount of different numbers won't increase. For same $r_{0,0}$ they produce same numbers with just a  different order. (They also need some settle in time but that's ok)

Comment: This seems like a good question, but it is not very clear exactly what you are looking for. I doubt there are any efficient random number generators that can be **proved** to satisfy your requirement that calculating $r(n)$ requires at least $n$ steps. It might help if you explained why you are looking for such random number generators.

Comment: The requirements "It should take $O(a b) \cdot O(f)$ operations to find $a,b$ from $v = r_{a,b}$" and "There exists an inverse function of $f_1, f_2$ with about the same computation time" seem incompatible. If an inverse function exists, I can find $a,b$ in $O(a+b) \cdot O(f)$ steps by seeing where the sequence $r_{0,0}, f_1(r_{0,0}), f_1(f_1(r_{0,0})), \dots$ equals $v, f_2^{-1}(v), f_2^{-1}(f_2^{-1}(v)), \dots$.

Comment: Does "$f_1(x)$ can produce $s_1$ unique numbers" mean that the range of $f_1$ has $s_1$ elements? In that case the range of $f_1\circ f_2$ cannot possibly be larger than that.

Comment: @RobArthan added some more info about target use case.

Comment: @HenningMakholm As far as I know this can only apply if $f$ have the same number in a different order. For this $f$ need another parameter (like $f(x,k)$) which also change for each new random number. As alternative $f$ can have a different number of elements depending on $r_{0,0}$ which can only be reached with using the other function. That should not work with commutative property. Or do I miss something? ty for response

Comment: @MishaLavrov uff, that's a good point, ty for that hint. That would destroy it all :(. The possibility of a short way is OK but the mean time need to be the product else use case wont work. Will think about your comment. Maybe there is some way around.

Comment: linear-shift feedback register is first thing that comes to mind

Comment: @MishaLavrov true for two functions. In use case I want to use 3 of them. With this it should be a product again (but only with two factors). $\mathcal{O}( (a + b)\cdot c)\mathcal{O}(f)$ ($a,b,c$ can be permutated to get lowsest value). Furthermore this strategy (also for two dim) need some storage $\mathcal{O}(a)$ and some time to compare one result with all other $\mathcal{O}(1)$ techniques can exist for this.

Comment: @phdmba7of12 linear-shift feedback registers look interesting but they are not commutative. At least in my tested example. Do they need a special form to be commutative with another initialization?